# For Sale! Three potentially useful palettes

Tags: discussion, site-tools

I wanted to learn how to make palettes, so I've made this bunch.

They are still beta, but I want to share them for cross-platform checking and bug hunting.

The functions aren't mine, and proper credit is included. I've made very few modifications to the original author's code in order to fit the palette programming requirements. A general credit to Szabolcs, from whom I've stolen the palettes' skeleton.

The master plan is integrating all the palettes once they are debugged enough.

**Installation instructions for all palettes**

You can download the palettes by executing the provided commands. After the download, a new notebook will open. Execute the (palette) code in the new notebook and you'll get something like this:

[image: click on me!]

Presto! You (should) see the palette.

---

### First one: [Heike's wonderful `torn[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4155/193)

[image: Mathematica graphics][image: Mathematica graphics]

Command to download:

```
NotebookPut@ImportString[Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Flatten@
            ImageData[Import@ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkLIy.png","Byte"],"NB"]
```

---

### Second one: [Mr. Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11402/193) to the xkcd fly catcher question

You'll need to install [this font](http://simonsoftware.se/other/xkcd.ttf) first.

[image]

Command to download:

```
NotebookPut@ImportString[Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Flatten@
            ImageData[Import@ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJueG.png","Byte"],"NB"]
```

---

### Third one: the generator for the download method used in the previous ones

A related discussion [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/626/193) (See Sjoerd's and my answers).

**Warning:** I've got mixed reports on this one. AFAIK it worked at least for Sjoerd and me (Win$). Linux and Mac users reported problems. Download it only if you agree with the potential usefulness of the method and you wish to help debugging.

Command to download:

```
NotebookPut@ImportString[Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Flatten@
            ImageData[Import@ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjjsf.png","Byte"],"NB"]
```

Comment: Feedback most welcome!

Comment: So, you're hiding the palette code in images you've stuck up on imgur? Clever.

Comment: @rcollyer The main idea isn't about "hiding" it, but about finding a safe place to share files that doesn't fit well in a question or answer, [like here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11589/193). This method hasn't been well received by the community ([see Sjoerd's and my answers here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/626/193)), but I find it very convenient sometimes.

Comment: You know I hadn't been paying attention to that conversation.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks. I downloaded the palettes and will give feedback if anything comes up.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig Will be much appreciated. Enjoy

Comment: @belisarius why don't you add the Upload the active notebook to SE? Is it somewhere else?

Comment: @chris It's the last one. It uploads the nb to SE and copies the downloading code to your clipboard

Comment: @belisarius It does not seem to work for me. I did get a notebook downloaded; when I run it I get a button  "Upload active Notebook to SE"; then I am confused: how can I get focus on any other notebook while pressing this button. In any case when I press this button it says "SEnbUploader`stackImage::err: Server returner error: You didn\'t enter a URL". Could you please guide me through this?

Comment: @chris Could you provide your OS and Mma version info?

Comment: MacOS 10.7.5 Mathematica 8.0.4

Comment: @chris can you come to chat?

Comment: @belisarius I wonder why the AspectRatio of the xkcdified plot is changed. Compare `Plot[Sin[x]*Cos[x], {x, -\[Pi], 3 \[Pi]}]` with the result which has a very different ratio.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig Yeap. It works well only when both scales are equal. I haven't spend time debugging it, though.

Comment: How's your plot labeling palette coming along? Any chance I could beta test it for you? (Yes, I can make use of it ...)

Comment: @rcollyer I've started working on it, found some problems and have put it on stand by until I find some time to continue. Not in the next few days, for sure. Feel free to use the code and make the palette yourself if you feel like so. Sorry :(

Comment: _To the future visitors who might face a problem while running the codes_: for some unknown reasons, the `Uncompress` function might not work as expected. So you have to split the code in two parts. i.e. `str = FromCharacterCode@Flatten@ImageData[Import@"the-encoded-picture.png","Byte"];    `  and then concatenate the string with one or maybe two zeros, like this: `NotebookPut@ImportString[Uncompress[str<>"0"], "NB"]`